# Apply opacity to a component when dragging and moving in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4.2

Is it possible to display a widget with opacity 70% when it is being dragged? In my case it is not even showing content of the widget when it is dragged rather just a red icon.

Any sample code would be helpful.

Please note that I am using ExtJS 4

Comment: Any update on this please?

Comment: can you please add your code or a simple fiddle of what you've done? how can we help you without any line of code

Comment: The code is huge. I am able to drag and drop a component into free space and everything works fine. The only remaining part is to display the component with an opacity of 70% when it is being dragged. So my question is how can we apply style for a component when it is being dragged? I am using Ext.dd.DragZone and Ext.dd.DropZone for this